# How to make a full-width macOS toolbar (titlebar accessory) in SwiftUI

Tags: macos, swiftui, width, toolbar, titlebar

Let’s start with a `NavigationSplitView`. It comes with a toggle sidebar button which is positioned and animated properly: (shown or hidden) ⨯ (fullscreen or windowed).

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
        } detail: {
        }
    }
}
```

I need a full-width toolbar, expanding from the trailing edge of the toggle button to the window's right edge. Just like this:

[image: expected appearance]

Let’s use a placeholder which is expanding in both direction:

```
struct Toolbar: View {
    var body: some View {
        Color.red
    }
}
```

The `.toolbar` modifier does not work, I guess that `ToolbarItem` does not get the size of its parent view or does not pass that to its children. So it is only 10 pt by 10 pt.

```
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
        Toolbar()
    }
}
```

My best take was to pair `NSHostingView` with `addTitlebarAccessoryViewController`:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
        let window = NSApplication.shared.windows[0]
        window.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
        window.titleVisibility = .hidden

        let toolbar = Toolbar()
        let titlebarAccessoryViewController = NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController()
        let titlebarAccessoryHostingView = NSHostingView(rootView: toolbar)
        titlebarAccessoryViewController.view = titlebarAccessoryHostingView
        titlebarAccessoryViewController.layoutAttribute = .trailing

        window.addTitlebarAccessoryViewController(titlebarAccessoryViewController)
        let toggle = window.toolbar!.items[0]
        let toggleView = toggle.view!

        titlebarAccessoryHostingView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        titlebarAccessoryHostingView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: toggleView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    }
}
```

It seems the auto layout constraint is buggy because the following runtime exception is thrown:

```
2023-01-13 14:09:41.128026+0700 FullWidthToolbar[40901:1231494] *** Assertion failure in -[NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController _auxiliaryViewFrameChanged:], NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController.m:341
2023-01-13 14:09:41.128277+0700 FullWidthToolbar[40901:1231494] [General] changing the view's origin is not allowed
2023-01-13 14:09:41.132215+0700 FullWidthToolbar[40901:1231494] [General] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001862e33e8 __exceptionPreprocess + 176
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000185e2eea8 objc_exception_throw + 60
    2   Foundation                          0x0000000187226910 -[NSCalendarDate initWithCoder:] + 0
    3   AppKit                              0x000000018954f764 -[NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController _auxiliaryViewFrameChanged:] + 376
```

Is this approach promising? How to fix the auto layout constraint?

I’ve tried to set the size of the toolbar using a `GeometryReader`, unfortunately, it makes the (show/hide sidebar, fullscreen enter/exit, resizing, etc.) animation glitchy.

Answer (score 1):

You're very close.

The `NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController` has two segments — the `NSView` or `NSHostingView` you assign in its `view` property, and an `NSClipView` which wraps that view. I'm not certain, but my guess is that the `NSClipView` gets used to handle overflow conditions when the window is too small to display all toolbar items.

In order to get the behavior you're wanting, you need to apply layout constraints to both your `NSHostingView` *and* the `NSClipView`. You'll also need to apply constraints to any other views which may be auto-generated by the type of window style you're using.

I have created a [gist for this](https://gist.github.com/stephancasas/d03f25bdf43c2ae55a41d70ec4f80e50) if you'd like to have a look. The key takeaways are:

- The `NSClipView` constraints:

```swift
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    accessoryClipView.leadingAnchor.constraint(
        equalTo: titlebarBlock.leadingAnchor,
        constant: 7),
    accessoryClipView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titlebarBlock.topAnchor),
    accessoryClipView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titlebarBlock.bottomAnchor),
]);
```

- The `NSHostingView` constraints:

```swift
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    accessoryView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: accessoryClipView.leadingAnchor),
    accessoryView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: accessoryClipView.trailingAnchor),
    accessoryView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: accessoryClipView.topAnchor),
    accessoryView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: accessoryClipView.bottomAnchor)
]);
```

- The `NSToolbarTitleView` constraints:

```swift
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    toolbarTitleView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: accessoryView.trailingAnchor)
]);
```

I explain the process to acquire and significance behind each of these elements in the gist.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks. But it seems the toolbar does not grow: https://imgur.com/a/SrLxoM8 Can you provide a working project?

Comment: Is this constraint still necessary? `accessoryClipView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo:  NSApplication.shared.windows[0].contentView!.trailingAnchor)`

Comment: Check-out this example implementation: https://github.com/stephancasas/swiftui-advanced-toolbar-app

I've included a screenshot in the repo for reference.

Comment: The question asks for a full-width (horizontal-expanding) toolbar next to the built-in toolbar controls (toggle sidebar, navigate back, etc.) The proposed solution is very very close (and enlightening). If we add the above `trailingAnchor` constraint, the toolbar view can horizontally expand to the trailing edge of the window. There are two things to note (1) dragging the divider between the toolbar and detail area to the right crashes the app (2) the built-in toolbar controls (toggle toolbar, etc) are missing.

Comment: I incorrectly assumed that you were already using `NSToolbar` to implement classic toolbar controls in the rightmost space.

For a truly full-width toolbar, you should split your controls into title toolbar and main toolbar — left and right of the window title, using the `.left` and `.right` constraints on the `NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController`. This will allow you to preserve the window title and avoid the fatal condition you described.

I've updated the example repo to accept a `withToolbar` arg in addition to the `withTitleToolbar` arg. Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Thanks for the update. (1) I do not need a title (`.windowStyle(.hiddenTitleBar)` already). (2) I do need the built-in toolbar controls (toggle sidebar, navigate back) to behave normally just like the picture in the question. PS: the update still crashes when dragging the divider and sometimes misplaces the toolbar https://imgur.com/a/ws9NEDz

Comment: I can't seem to replicate the behavior you're describing. Are you running Ventura, or another version of macOS?

Comment: I’m using 13.3. It’s not that hard to reproduce. Just drag the divider left (do not release the mouse/trackpad) to close the sidebar and you will see the misplacement. Drag it right and you see the crash.

Comment: FYI: https://imgur.com/a/3Sla5yD

Comment: My guess is that when the sidebar collapses, one of the objects on which the constraints are based gets deallocated. There's probably a way to fix this by adding an observer to the superview and applying/releasing constraints, but I'll need to read more into that lifecycle to come up with an answer. If you think of something, please do tell!